# Update another table based on latest record

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the below table (sorry couldn't figure out how to post a table... in bold are the field names)

**code  desc    channel     date**

1001    A       supermarket 10-oct

1001    B       minimarket  15-dic

1003    A       restaurant  07-may

1003    B       bar         30-abr

1003    A       restaurant  12-dic

1002    B       kiosk       10-oct

I am trying to get the latest record for each code and update it in another table where I have already all the codes I need to be updated (on this table I have the same fields but needed to update them to the latest)

the result would be this

**code  des channel date**

1001    B   minimarket   15-dic

1003    A   restaurant   12-dic

1002    B   kiosk   1    0-oct

thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you have real dates, or strings, as shown? With real dates you can use Max.

Comment: Why are storing dates like this. Always use proper datatype which will simply your problems

Comment: This would me much easier with a primary key field.  Is there one?

Comment: @Fionnuala: the dates are real ones. I pasted in excel to check and then repasted here... excel might have converted it to this format.

Comment: @hpf: the primary key in the second table is the code. in the source table there is none as it appears with different dates....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results using a query:

```
select t.*
from table as t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date) from table as t2 where t2.code = t.code);
```

I'm not sure what your other table looks like, but you could fix this into a query like:

```
update secondtable
    set val = (select channel
               from table as t
               where t.code = secondtable.code and
                     t.date = (select max(t2.date) from table as t2 where t2.code = t.code)
             );
```

You could also use a `join` if more than one field were being set.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer (as the others posted work also) is to use a temporary table.  It does require 3 SQL statements, but might be faster than the nested queries below:

(assuming the two tables you have are called t1 and t2, and I use MySQL)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t3 AS
SELECT code, descr, channel, MAX(date) as mxdate  <--- I would avoid using "desc" and "date" if possible
FROM t1
GROUP BY code;

UPDATE t2,t3
SET t2.descr=t3.descr, t2.channel=t3.channel, t2.date=t3.mxdate
WHERE t2.code=t3.code;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE t3;
```

Not sure if this is faster.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a problem for Access. It's pretty much the same as Gordon's answer but it does also show you how to write the update for multiple columns.

```
update T2
set desc = (
        select t.desc
        from T as t inner join
            (select code, max(date) as maxdate ftom t group by code) as m
            on m.code = t.code and m.maxdate = t.date
        where t.code = T2.code
    ),
    channel = (
        select t.channel
        from T as t inner join
            (select code, max(date) as maxdate ftom t group by code) as m
            on m.code = t.code and m.maxdate = t.date
        where t.code = T2.code
    ),
    date = (
        select t.date
        from T as t inner join
            (select code, max(date) as maxdate ftom t group by code) as m
            on m.code = t.code and m.maxdate = t.date
        where t.code = T2.code
    )
```