# MYSQL update from another table with multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have seen a bunch of helpful answers about updating table values from a different table with multiple values based on a timestamp using a MAX() subquery.

e.g. [Update another table based on latest record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050917/update-another-table-based-on-latest-record)

I was wondering how this compares with doing an ALTER first and relying on the order in the table to simplify the UPDATE. Something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `table_with_multiple_data` ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC;

UPDATE `table_with_single_data` as `t1` 
  LEFT JOIN `table_with_multiple_data` AS `t2` 
  ON `t1`.`id`=`t2`.`t1id` 
  SET `t1`.`value` = `t2`.`value`;
```

(Apologies for the pseudocode but I hope you get what I'm asking)

Both achieve the same for me but don't really have a big enough data set to see any difference in speed.

Thanks!!

Comment: **Never** rely on some **assumed** order of records within a table.

Comment: The result would not do the same: in SQL order is not guaranteed, so having the data in your table in order does not guarantee anything in a SQL statement (Most of the time this would show the result you expect, but sometimes it just will not): If the data is already in memory for example, the database engine might decide to execute the join order different than you expect.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there may be some reason that the ALTER method answer never came up before!!!

Answer (score 1):

You would normally use a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE table_with_single_data t1
  SET t1.value = (select t2.value
                  from table_with_multiple_data t2
                  where t2.t1id = t1.id 
                  order by t2.timestamp desc
                  limit 1
                 );
```

If your method happens to work, that is just happenstance.  Even if MySQL respected the ordering of tables, such ordering would not survive the `join` operation.  Not to mention the fact that there is no guarantee on *which * value is assigned when there is multiple matching rows.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to get a very slightly different version of this working nicely!